# EntityFramework CodeFirst Ignoring MaxLength

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm working with SQL Server Compact. For each table I have a Configuration that contains a MaxLength property.

I run Add-Migration and it generates correctly the create column string with maxlength, but when I run Update-Database the column is being created with NVARCHAR(MAX)

```
public class Test{
    public string TestField { get; set; }
}

public class TestConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Test>
    {
        public TestConfiguration()
        {

            Property(o => o.TestField)
                .HasMaxLength(100);


        }
    }
```

My DB Context Class:

```
public class PlutoContext : DbContext
{
    public PlutoContext()
        : base("name=PlutoContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer<PlutoContext>(null);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TestConfiguration());
    }
```

**Generated Migration**

```
public partial class AddTest : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Test",
            c => new
                {
                   Test = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
    }

}
```

Why Framework is not respecting the MaxLength property? Thanks!

Comment: Everything I see here looks right.  The only thing that's different from me is that you're using SQL Compact Edition. Perhaps that is causing the issue?  Perhaps try it against regular SQL just to see if it works.

Comment: SQL Server Compact does not have a nvarchar(max) datatype - where do you see this?

Comment: hi @ErikEJ I'm using LINQPad

Comment: Maybe is a LINQPad bug? I executed the SQL: alter table Orders alter column Test NVARCHAR(100) and I keep seeing NVARCHAR(MAX) at Table's description.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to add something like the line below in `OnModelCreating` part of context:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TestConfiguration());
```